# App not showing when click on notification on Android

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic4, ionic-native, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using Ionic v4 to create an app that is able to receive notifications (by topic) by using the cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated plugin.

At this moment everything works as supposed on IOS. I receive a notification and when I click on it, the onNotification event gets triggered and it redirects me to the app, on the page that I selected.

However, Android does not work like that. I would expect the same behavior as mentioned above, but for some reason the app is openend, but the  onNotification event does not get triggered. I had some console.logs and alert placed inside, but none of them showed.

I then read the I had to add the click_send parameter to the notification body, with value FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY.
Now this will give me an even more strange behavior: I do receive the notification, but clicking on it, will not even open the app! Also nothing in the logs...

Can anybody help me out here, I'm getting lost!

PS. just updated every npm package to @latest...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, all that had to be done was:

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

and:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

to refresh things.
Now everything works as expected...

Comment: Yes it normal when you add a plugin  , you need to remove add platform.